# Total newbie confusion with pandoc and changing fonts on pdf export

Tags: fonts, pandoc

I have `pandoc` and would like to change the awful default font when I convert a .MD to a .PDF.

I understand I can pass `-V` on the command line and that `pandoc` uses `--pdf-engine=pdflatex` by default. I would like to change the font family to `https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/clearsans/`. I try:

```
pandoc -V fontfamily="ANYTHING" test.md -o test.pdf
```

and just get

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: File `ANYTHING.sty' not found.
```

I am reading about different engines, which don't seem to be installed. I can look at a config file that is total mumbo-jumbo.

Can I just list what fonts or font family's are available and choose one on the command line?

I installed `texlive` on Centos 8 and it installed a lot... but there seems still more packages. It seems a lot of work to change a font!

```
tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
```

also I see included in the install were:

```
Name         : texlive-latex-fonts
Summary      : A collection of fonts used in LaTeX distributions
URL          : http://tug.org/texlive/
License      : LPPL
Description  : This is a collection of fonts for use with standard latex
             : packages and classes. It includes 'invisible' fonts (for use
             : with the slides class), line and circle fonts (for use in the
             : picture environment) and 'latex symbol' fonts. For full support
             : of a latex installation, some Computer Modern font variants
             : cmbsy(6-9), cmcsc(8,9), cmex(7-9) and cmmib(5-9) from the
             : amsfonts distribution, are also necessary. The fonts are
             : available as Metafont source, and metric (tfm) files are also
             : provided. Most of the fonts are also available in Adobe Type 1
             : format, in the amsfonts distribution.

Name         : texlive-collection-basic
Summary      : Essential programs and files
URL          : http://tug.org/texlive/
License      : Artistic 2.0 and GPLv2 and GPLv2+ and LGPLv2+ and LPPL and MIT
             : and Public Domain and UCD and Utopia
Description  : These files are regarded as basic for any TeX system, covering
             : plain TeX macros, Computer Modern fonts, and configuration for
             : common drivers; no LaTeX.

Name         : texlive-collection-fontsrecommended
Summary      : Recommended fonts
URL          : http://tug.org/texlive/
License      : Artistic 2.0 and GPLv2 and GPLv2+ and LGPLv2+ and LPPL and MIT
             : and Public Domain and UCD and Utopia
Description  : Recommended fonts, including the base 35 PostScript fonts,
             : Latin Modern, TeX Gyre, and T1 and other encoding support for
             : Computer Modern, in outline form.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: have you tried with a standard TeXLive font first ? (like `lmodern`)

Answer (score 4):

On a recent TeX Live installation

```
pandoc -V fontfamily:ClearSans -V fontfamilyoptions:sfdefault test.md -o test.pdf
```

should work. To make sure that the right package is installed use the package manager `tlmgr`¹

```
tlmgr install clearsans
```

---

1. Maybe you need to use `sudo`, depending on your installation

Comment: Afraid I get `! LaTeX Error: File ClearSans.sty not found.` There is no `tlmgr` on my system or available. There are no `.sty` files on my computer!

Comment: Looks like the TL shipped with CentOS is defective. I suggest you remove ist and install a vanilla TL. This tutorial is for CentOS7 but it should work also with 8: https://www.systutorials.com/241660/how-to-install-tex-live-on-centos-7-linux/

Comment: I am very reluctant to use anything other than the official packages. Centos 8.1 is RHEL 8.1 which is the most stable and trusted distro, can't believe it has a bug so big that none of the fonts work in TL! What can I do to confirm that TL can see fonts, can I list installed without `tlmgr`? Cheers!

Comment: @Sumomo --- What happens if you enter `kpsewhich ClearSans.sty` in the terminal?

Comment: Well TeX on linux distributions is a critical topic, discussed extensively [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=linux+packages). If you don't want to install TeX Live manually (still recommended) you should install all the extra packages, try: `yum install texlive-scheme-full`. Or you could figure out, which package provides the fonts you seek: `sudo yum whatprovides '*/ClearSans.sty'`